# For Loops Errors

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>For Loop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        for(v=0;v<10;v++){
        document.write("Hello World <br />");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my for loop code in this code I have written that `v=0;v<10;v++` so It needs to print out `Hello World` only 9 time but it is printing 10 time since I have put `v<10` so this is my question why this is happening I am using firefox it is updated browser in windows 8.1 . I am following this tutorial to learn JavaScript - http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=10&number=19

Comment: Remember that you start with `0`. That's why, if you say `v` must be smaller than 10, it is still printed 10 times.

Comment: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: Please can you send me sample It will be more helpful for me to understand because I am a biggener .thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the answer of BastetFurry. It visualizes very well what is going on in your example code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, it is just basic math.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for Helping me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it starts on 0. Try editing your print line to this and see for yourself:

```
document.write("Hello World: " + v + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

because you start counting at 0 in your for loop, while you confuse it with counting in real life. 0-based index vs 1-based index.

0 to 10 = 11 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). 0 to 9 = 10.

Don't confuse this with how we, as humans, count.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is executing 10 times for following v values

1. v=0
2. v=1
3. v=2
4. v=3
5. v=4
6. v=5
7. v=6
8. v=7
9. v=8
10. v=9

Thus it is printing 10 times

Change your for loop as below

```
for(v=1; v<10; v++)
```

Or

```
for(v=0; v<9; v++)
```

Or

```
for(v=1; v<=9; v++)
```